# Powershell - Get array2 elements using values from array1

Tags: powershell

I have two arrays and I want to get array2 number of elements by looping through array1 based on the value of each element of array1

```
$array1 = @(2,1,3)
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array2 = "string1",'string2','string3','string4','string5','string6'

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $array1.Length; $i++) {
        $cod_nr = $array1[$i] - 1
    
        for ($x=0; $x -le $cod_nr; $x++) {
           ... missing logic ...
           Basically here I should get first $array1[-] elements of array2 every run
       
        }
       (remove array collected element - maybe this step should be in the for loop above)
       missing logic
    }
```

Basically, I want to get the following output:
1st run (get 2 elements [array1[0,1]:
$my_variable = "string1, string2"

2nd run (get 1 element $array1[2] - number of the element will change if a element is removed):
$my_variable = "string3"

3rd run (get 3 elements $array1[3,4,5] - number of the element will change if a element is removed):
$my_variable = "string4, string5, string6"

Comment: [1] keep track of the starting index [zero for the 1st set]. ///// [2] calc the ending index number. ///// [3] use an index range like `$Collection[3..5]` to get the items you want.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm wondering why are you approaching it this way, there is probably a more easy and reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: I have a CSV file with column A with 10 rows thwt contains some names, column B that has 10 rows  that contains diff number from which I create array1 and another column with 25 rows from which array2 results. Sum of all array1 emenets is equal with total nr of array2 elements (25 în my example). If first element of array1 is [int]2 then first 2 elements of array2 will be allocated to user1 from column A. If array1 second element is [int]1 then the 3rd element of inițial array2 will be allocated and so on

Comment: I can't really understand all that. Perhaps if you could explain the _problem_ rather than your attempted _solution_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we could understand what you're *actually* trying to solve, the advice will probably be different.

However, for your specific request, here is how I would handle it.

```
$array1 = 2,1,3
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array2 = "string1",'string2','string3','string4','string5','string6'

foreach($element in $array1){

    $my_variable = $array2[0..($element - 1)]

    Write-Host my_variable contains $my_variable

    $array2.RemoveRange(0,$element)
}
```

Since you always want the first X elements, it's rather easy. Just grab those and then remove them. No need to use a for loop.

Output

```
my_variable contains string1 string2
my_variable contains string3
my_variable contains string4 string5 string6
```

Comment: I have a CSV file with column A with 10 rows thwt contains some names, column B that has 10 rows  that contains diff number from which I create array1 and another column with 25 rows from which array2 results. Sum of all array1 emenets is equal with total nr of array2 elements (25 în my example). If first element of array1 is [int]2 then first 2 elements of array2 will be allocated to user1 from column A. If array1 second element is [int]1 then the 3rd element of inițial array2 will be allocated and so on. Thanks for your answer, I will test tommorow this the soluiton without removing from ar2

Comment: I've tested and this is what I was looking for. So easy... Thanks a lot!